# What type of cookies are automatically extracted by HTTP Cookie Manager component of Jmeter?

Tags: cookies, jmeter, performance-testing

As the HTTP Cookie Manager stores and sends cookies like a web browser does

Some of the cookies are automatically extracted & stored and other are to be explicitly defined using User defined cookie field in it .What type of cookies are picked automatically by Cookie manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All valid cookies for sent request are extracted by JMeter as per the RFC.

JMeter does not save by default invalid cookies or cross domain ones.

You can change this behaviour by setting property :
- CookieManager.check.cookies=false

Read this:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

The values you enter in table are those you want to send and that were not previously set by server for example:

- you want to simulate cookie persistant basket on a website
- you create a set of baskets each one with an id that will be in cookie
- you put those ids in a CSV, use a CSV Dataset in Jmeter exporting variable basketId
- you then use Cookie Manager and put in the table basketId=${basketId}

Comment: Please suggest a scenario in which defining cookies manually would be more appropriate or would be the only option

Comment: shouldn't be ${COOKIE_basketId} instead of ${basketID} in order to use it or is it that manually created cookies can be used like regular jmeter variables?

Comment: not for the one coming from csv, yes for those that are saved as variables

Answer (score 2):

There's no single right answer unfortunately. Generally anything coming via `Set-Cookie` header in the response, will at least be evaluated by JMeter and considered for storage within cookie manager. But results of the evaluation depend on 3 parameters, so in the end of the day the following cookies will be saved:

- A small simple rule: if cookie is `null`, `CookieManager.delete_null_cookies` parameter in `jmeter.properties` decides whether such cookie will be further evaluated or discarded. By default cookies with null value are discarded.
- Cookies are further evaluated, based on selected **Cookie Policy** for the selected **Implementation** (those 2 parameters you specify in UI). For HC3CookieHandler implementation the default is a **compatibility** policy, which is described as:

  > The policy that provides high degree of compatibility with common cookie management of popular HTTP agents.

  For HC4CookieHandler, the default policy is **standard**, which is described as

  > State management policy compliant with a more relaxed profile defined by RFC 6265, section 4 intended for interoperability with existing servers that do not conform to the well behaved profile.

JMeter docs do not say much about all the cookie policies, although they are the most important factor in save/don't save decision. Mostly policies are related to security and specs of the cookies (for example accept 3rd-party cookies or not; accept cookies with missing fields or not; consider sub-domains to be 3rd-party cookies or not). The following pages give you a summary of policies: [for version 3](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html) (matches HC3CookieHandler implementation) and [version 4](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html) (matches HC4CookieHandler). But for full details on what each policy accepts and rejects, you'd have to dig into RFCs.

Comment: nice answer. For info docs have. been improved in jmeter 3.0, check it out and give your feedback